# DataBinding doesn't work after upgrading to gradle plugin 2.3

Tags: android, gradle-plugin, annotation-processing

After upgrading to `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'` and [migrating](https://bitbucket.org/hvisser/android-apt/wiki/Migration) to build-in annotation processor I got following error for all my DataBinding generated classes:

```
  :app:compileInternalDebugJavaWithJavac
  E:\Projects\Work-projects\mediteo-android\app\src\main\java\com\mediteo\mobile\presentation\daily\intake\adapter\DailyIntakeItem.java:18: error: package com.mediteo.mobile.databinding does not exist
  import com.mediteo.mobile.databinding.DailyIntakeHeaderItemBinding;
                                 ^
  E:\Projects\Work-projects\mediteo-android\app\src\main\java\com\mediteo\mobile\presentation\daily\intake\adapter\DailyIntakeItem.java:19: error: package com.mediteo.mobile.databinding does not exist
  import com.mediteo.mobile.databinding.DailyIntakeItemBinding;
  ........
  Error:A default public constructor with no argument must be declared in IntakeLocal if a custom constructor is declared.
  * What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileInternalDebugJavaWithJavac'.
  > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

However I can navigate to those files in Android studio IDE

```
  public class DailyIntakeHeaderItemBinding extends android.databinding.ViewDataBinding  { 
  ........
```

Answer (score 0):

Try invalidate caches/restart. Or may be clean build.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was in new annotation processing command `annotationProcessor` it is worth to pay attention to all libraries that used `apt` (now `annotationProcessor`) The root cause was `Error:A default public constructor with no argument must be declared in IntakeLocal if a custom constructor is declared.`, this is error throw by dagger.

To fix this I have to update lombok to latest version:
`org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.14`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and could fix it by adding this to the app build.gradle dependencies:

```
apt 'com.android.databinding:compiler:2.3.0'
```